# Svelte Store: Am I missing the point of the stores subscribe method?

Tags: svelte-component, svelte-store

I am learning Svelte and attempting to build a simple SPA. So far the biggest thing that doesn't make any sense to me is the subscribe method for stores. In all of the examples on [svelte.dev](https://svelte.dev/examples/writable-stores) its only used to link to an unsubscribe method for when a component is unMounted/Destroyed.

On top of that, when I create my store I have done this.

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

const store = writable(0);

function Notify()
{
    store.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
}

function DoThing(newValues)
{
   store.update(oldValues => oldValues = newValues);
   Notify();
}
```

But in my logs, it still runs twice. Even though I am only calling it after my `store.update` call.

Would greatly appreciate any explanations on what I could be misunderstanding or doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.subscribe()` only has to be called once - then the subscription is active. So in your case you don't need `Notify()` (Since you don't modify the current value but only want to set a new one, you can use `.set()` instead of `.update()`)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1fe9475968374a869ba79373513a7af2?version=3.49.0)

```html
<script>
    import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

    const store = writable(0);

    store.subscribe(value => console.log(value));

    function doThing(newValue)  {
        store.set(newValue)
    }

</script>

<button on:click={() => doThing(Math.random())}>
    doThing
</button>
```

Calling `.subscribe()` returns a function which can be used to cancel the subscription

```js
const unsubscribe = count.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
});

unsubscribe(); // subscription canceled
```